# How to make a randomForest algorithm cost-sensitive?

Tags: random-forest

Having used randomForest in R to produce a fairly successful classifier is there any way to emphasise sensitivity over specificity, for example, if the cost of missing a disease is much greater than diagnosing a false positive?

Comment: Looks like the bst package in R will accept weights for false positive and false negatives. I'm going to leave the question open though, It might be useful to others.

Comment: http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2105-10-S1-S22.pdf Using random forest for reliable classification and cost-sensitive learning for medical diagnosis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't actually know R package, but if you were able to decrease the cost of **False Positives** it should work. This is also the rationale of MetaCost by Domingos, that is implemented in WEKA. However, increasing the *sensitivity* you are going to decrease the *specificity*, naturally. From the information retrieval point of view, as long as you increase the *recall* the *precision* will decrease.

Because Random Forest use Decision Trees as base classifiers and they can output probabilities, you can decrease the cut-off that enable a tree to classify a record as positive. This will make you Random Forest more sensitive but less precise.

Comment: Sure. I'll add that in case of randomForest, OOB votes are in `votes` element of the `randomForest` object; for prediction, one must use `predict` with `type="votes"` or `type="prob"`.

Comment: ...and here's and example on how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130053/roc-for-random-forest/31149340?noredirect=1#comment50311605_31149340

Comment: Also another option is to use the weighted Gini gain http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69335/2719